# Make navigation via NSString? or Make UILabel/UITextview contents for navigation

Tags: objective-c, ios, navigation, uitextview, uilabel

I have string data and height is changable, it can be like this:

John Colman to
   Android Market, Iphone Developers, PHP grups

or just

John Colman to
   Edward Python

but except "to" all the words must be navigate other viewController? What is the best solution for this? It is easy the navigate something via UITableView delegate or UIButton but it is just NSString??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used open framework of facebook:
http://three20.info/

create an linkable textlabel and it works..